# Angular - multiple select with one options array

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, logic

In my component I have array of options like:

```
options = [
    {
      name: 'option 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'option 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'option 3'
    }
];
```

Then in my view I have multiple selects:

```
<form>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let o of options" 
            [value]="o">{{o.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let o of options" 
            [value]="o">{{o.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let o of options" 
            [value]="o">{{o.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

All of them are using the same `options` array. What I want to achieve is:

If in first select, option 1 has been selected: second and third select have only option 2 and 3. Then if for example third select pick option 2, second select has only what is left (option 3).

In addition `options` array and amount of `mat-select` HTML elements are dynamic, so for example I could have:

> options.lenght = 3 and 2x `mat-select`
>
> options.lenght = 2 and 2x `mat-select`
>
> options.lenght = 2 and 1x `mat-select`
>
> ...et cetera

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could add another attribute to each option that says whether the option is selected or not. Then when it is clicked you can change that attribute and the use *ngIf to control the display. Additionally, you can track which input the option has been selected in by passing in the input's label as another attribute.

```
options = [
    {
      name: 'option 1',
      selected: false,
      labelName: ""
    },
    {
      name: 'option 2',
      selected: false,
      labelName: ""
    },
    {
      name: 'option 3',
      selected: false,
      labelName: ""
    }
];
```

Hopefully, I correctly understood what you're trying to do.